# How to save a report with data in the HTML format? (OBIEE 12c)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, obiee

I go from "weblogic". I translated the text in the format of HTML. When saving, it gives the following error:
[image]

I found the Instanceconfig.xml file and added code like this to it:

```
 <Security>

<CheckUrlFreshness> false </CheckUrlFreshness>
<EnableSavingContentWithHTML> true </EnableSavingContentWithHTML>

</Security>
```

But this did not help, it is still impossible to save data in HTML format.

Comment: There are as of today about 40 "12c" versions. Please specify and exact version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should grant the Application Role the appropriate privilege from the Analytics webpage under Manage > Privileges > Answers > **Save Content with HTML Markup**